# Whats the difference between [TestClass] and [TestClassAttribute] in MSTest?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, mstest

im about to inform my self about unit testing in visual studio.

I went on msdn, and it says that the [TestClassAttribute] Syntax define a TestClass. Well, fine. But when i create a simple unit Test with in Visual Studio, it decorates the testclass with the [TestClass] Syntax.

So, **where are the differences between [TestClass] and [TestClassAttribute]?** Or is [TestClass] just a short form?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Every Attribute class can have the sufix omitted. So you are right, TestClass and TestClassAttribute are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every class that derives from `System.Attribute`, also your own custom attributes, can have the text "Attribute" omitted if the class name ends with it.

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN:

> Attribute elements, whose names conclude with the string Attribute,
>   can be used either with or without the string Attribute. For example,
>   the following two code examples function identically: [TestClass()]
>   [TestClassAttribute()]